# Update Jenkins view automatically

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am working on some automation and I need to update the view programmatically.

UseCase: I have a jenkins view where I add all the jobs based on the release number and I do that by giving regular expression here-
[image]

I want to update this regular expression through script.

Is it possible to do the same through a groovy script?

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient to answer the question. Can you elaborate on your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can update the regex filters from Groovy. I have come up with the following with the limited information you have given. You may have to improve it based on the options you have enabled in your view.

```
def viewObj = Jenkins.instance.getView("VIEWNAME")
List<hudson.views.ViewJobFilter> jobFilters = new ArrayList<>()

jobFilters.add(new hudson.views.RegExJobFilter('.*NEWREGEX', "includeMatched", "NAME"))
viewObj.setJobFilters(jobFilters)
```